# How do I visit localhost with query string in Firefox?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, ubuntu-14.04

I can easily access my localhost via latest Firefox(updated a minute ago) if it has no query string in it. See below
[image]

But I want to send some parameters in query string ...

See this

[image]

It only allows me to search on Google. I want to hit that URL on localhost.

I have applied this solution and restarted FF. But no use.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1099228

Do I have to switch my OS? :P

Comment: Relevant Info: [URL Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax) – “The path **must** begin with a single slash (/) if an authority part was present”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox appears to require either the scheme to be specified, or the path to be non-empty, when query is present:

- `localhost:5000/?foo=bar`
- `http://localhost:5000?foo=bar`

Answer (score 0):

Well, take a look at Google's query:

```
https://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=rc82WKLfJ6fL8gfSoa-QCw
```

If we just change google's domain to its ip it becomes:

```
https://216.58.194.99/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=rc82WKLfJ6fL8gfSoa-QCw
```

So try this way:

```
localhost:5000/?abc=dsa
```

Or:

```
127.0.0.1:5000/?abc=dsa
```